# How box() is adopting max width after resizing terminal

Tags: c, ncurses, xterm

I don't know how reexecuting the function **box()** is adopting max width automatically and here is test code :

```
getmaxyx(stdscr,y,x);
      WINDOW *titleWin = update_title_win(NULL,2,x,0,0);
      while((ch = getch()) != 27) {
          if(ch == KEY_RESIZE) {
              update_title_win(titleWin);
          }
      }
```

update_title_win() code :

```
WINDOW* update_title_win(WINDOW *win, int height, int width, int y, int x)
{
    if(!win)
        win = newwin(height,width,y,x);
    box(win,0,0);
    refresh();
    wrefresh(win);
    return win;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ncurses library uses `resizeterm` to do the adjustments when `getch` returns `KEY_RESIZE`.  That function will reduce the size of windows if the (terminal/screen) shrinks, but the behavior when the screen increases in size is less apparent.

The manual page for [`resizeterm`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html#h3-resizeterm) does not mention this, but a [comment](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/e38c722bafedc8fe2d438bf026258fad22971d40/ncurses/base/resizeterm.c#L309) in the source code explains the behavior:

```
/*
 * If we're increasing size, recursively search for windows that have no
 * parent, increase those to fit, then increase the contained window, etc.
 */
```

A window created with [`newwin`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/resizeterm.3x.html#h3-resizeterm) has no parent (unlike something made with [`subwin`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html#h3-subwin)).  Since the `titleWin` started off with the full width of the screen, as the screen width changes, ncurses will attempt to keep the title window full-width.